# How do I create an offscreen UITextField

Tags: iphone

How would I create an Offscreen UITextField? Would it be:

```
theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 280, 44)];
```

Would I just have to set x and y at 1000, 1000. for example or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making x your negative width (-280) and y your negative height (-44) should do the trick.
Unless you start moving the bounds of the superview of course...

Comment: Excellent works treat! I asked the question to help solve another problem I had here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658261/uitextfield-subview-of-uitableviewcell-to-become-first-responder